# Is it bad to leave a server logged in if it's physically secure?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a headless Windows Server 2008 R2 box running at home, and I've just installed Plex on it to stream my media library. The software works brilliantly, but doesn't run as a service.

The simplest solution seems to be to leave a user logged into the server, so Plex can run.

If anyone breaks into my house then obviously they could connect a mouse, keyboard and monitor, but I think I'll have bigger issues in that case than worrying about my media library!

Are there any other security considerations?

Comment: Do you lock the screen when you leave it (if for no other reason than children, or cats walking a across the keyboard)?

Comment: It doesn't have a screen - it's only ever accessed using RDP from another PC.

Comment: As long as the user account will lock itself after a period of time, I don't see the problem, this currently happens when you log into the server through a remote desktop connection and the says session expires after an hour of no activity.